# Learning about Nested Stack Automata

Tags: fl.formal-languages, automata-theory, turing-machines, grammars

I want to learn about nested stack automata. However my efforts to find a suitable learning resource have so far been abortive:

1. The Wikipedia article on [nested stack automata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_stack_automaton) is a stub.
2. Alfred Aho's original paper on nested stack automata is [available on ACM](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=321529). However it's not free and I don't have the means to pay for it.
3. I've read the [paper on nested stack automata](http://www.math.stevens.edu/~rgilman/rhg/nsa.pdf) written by Robert Gilman and Michael Shapiro several times but the concept, to me, is still abstruse.

I really want to learn about nested stack automata. Hence it would be nice if somebody could explain, in a rigorous manner, how a nested stack automaton works.

In addition if you could link me to some good articles which explain nested stack automata then that would be great. Perhaps you have a soft copy of Alfred Aho's original paper on nested stack automata and are willing to share it?

Comment: You can email Al and I am positive he will send you a copy of his paper.